# C# How to implement polymorphism in a functional style?

Tags: c#, reflection, functional-programming, polymorphism

I have some OOP code that I am wanting to translate into a functional style, using only immutable types and with only freestanding (`static`) side-effect-free functions.

Here is a *much simplified* version of one scenario:

```
abstract class Thing { }

class Sphere : Thing {
    public readonly double Radius;
     public Sphere(double r) { Radius = r; }
}

class Cube : Thing {
     public readonly double Side;
     public Cube(double s) { Side = s; }
}
```

Previously, `Thing` defined an abstract method, `void Grow(double ratio)`. I have converted the two concrete implementations into freestanding static functions:

```
Sphere Grow(Sphere s, double ratio) => new Sphere(s.Radius*ratio);
Cube Grow(Cube c, double ratio) => new Cube(c.Side * ratio);
```

In the OOP version, I could use polymorphism to enumerate over a collection of type `Thing` and cause each to grow e.g.:

```
things.foreach(x => x.Grow(r));
```

But how can I do this in the functional approach?  I know I can write e.g. this:

```
Thing Grow(Thing t, double ratio) => t switch
{
     Sphere s => Grow(s, ratio),
     Cube c => Grow(c, ratio),
     _ => throw new Exception()
};
```

and

```
things.Select(t => Grow(t, r))
```

but I don't like the idea of having to extend the switch expression for each new implementation of Thing that I add.

I can see a way (I think) to do it using reflection, but am not keen on that for other reasons.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the equivalent of OOP polymorphism using functional patterns? (in C#, that is  -  I know it can be done in e.g. Haskell).

Comment: If you showed the code for the *"Let's say I have..."* example, and showed us what you think you want to get to (as code), people could follow along what you are thinking. This site works *much* better when questions have code. For what it's worth, in my last job, someone created a functionally-programmed service like you describe. It was a horrible beast to understand and was very fragile during maintenance (in part because of the issues you are running into)

Comment: I was trying not to make the post too long. But I have now edited to provide a more concrete example. N.B. this is a great simplification: I'm not after an answer that just solves this one specific simplified example, but the point in general about polymorphism.

Comment: Your perspective is a little biased for OOP: [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). You are looking for type class polymorphism, which is basically ad-hoc polymorphism where the mapping of overloaded names to types is itself given a name. Then you can relate different overloaded names, assign laws to them and arrange them hierarchically. I think the expression problem is solved with a more advanced functional technique called final tagless encoding, but this is beyond my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define and use generic interface for `Grow` method like this.

```
interface IGrowable<T> where T: Thing { 
    T Grow(T t, double ratio);
}

class Sphere : Thing, IGrowable<Sphere> {
    public readonly double Radius;
    public Sphere(double r) { Radius = r; }
    public Sphere Grow(Sphere s, double ratio) => new Sphere(s.Radius*ratio);

}

class Cube : Thing, IGrowable<Cube> {
     public readonly double Side;
     public Cube(double s) { Side = s; }
     public Cube Grow(Cube c, double ratio) => new Cube(c.Side * ratio);
}
```

```
IEnumerable<IGrowable<T>> GrowOwn<T>(IEnumerable<IGrowable<T>> grows, double ratio){
    return grows.Select(x => x.Grow(x,ratio));
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use reflection, define these class

```
public abstract class Thing {}

public class Sphere : Thing {
    public readonly double Radius;
    public Sphere(double r) { Radius = r; }
    public Sphere(Sphere s, double ratio){ Radius = s.Radius * ratio; }
}

public class Cube : Thing {
     public readonly double Side;
     public Cube(double s) { Side = s; }
     public Cube(Cube c, double ratio){ Side = c.Side * ratio; }
}
```

and this.

```
T Grow<T>(T thing, double ratio) where T: Thing => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T) , thing,  ratio);
```

You can get `Thing` object from this function.
But there is a risk of `MissingMethodException`. And reflection is not fast.
([see .NET's design goal](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/Documentation/botr/type-system.md#design-goals-and-non-goals), and using Expression Tree might help processing speed)

Comment: 1. What is 'things' defined as - it can't be a List<IGrowable<T>>?

Comment: 2. If I were to lose the requirement to return its own type, and just return a Thing, then this could work  -  BUT it is really just back to OOP i.e. the classes have instance methods, albeit they are now side-effect free.